# Displaying oEmbed errors?

Tags: errors, media, oembed

Sometimes embedding an item via oEmbed is not possible, for example when a YouTube video has embedding disabled. [The oEmbed service will return a `401 Unauthorized`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14377), and the code will not be converted.

Is there a way to notify the user of this? The current workflow is non-intuitive (at least to me), and I would prefer a message on the WordPress page, or even better, in the editor, saying that the object could not be embedded.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with current code.

`WP_oEmbed` object goes extra mile (more like miles) to sanitize input so it is either html or boolean `false`. All errors with fetching are discarded on output, there are no filters in there and only error (hardcoded) it handles is `501 not implemented`.

Earliest you can mess with this is somewhere down in HTTP API.

Comment: Maybe instead of hooking into the HTTP API, we could override the `WP_Embed` class, and let it use our own version of the `WP_oEmbed` class. We only need to override the `$wp_embed` global variable (and unhook the handlers set up in the constructor). But indeed, there is no easy support for this.